# For what values of $n$ does the measurability of $(f(x))^n$ implies the measurability of $f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

For what values of $n$ does the measurability of $(f(x))^n$ implies the measurability of $f(x)$?

Is there a general relationship between the measurability this two functions?

Comment: When $n$ is odd: $x\mapsto\sqrt[n]x$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 4):

If $n$ is odd the  $f$ is the composition of $f^{n}$ with the continuous function $x \to x^{1/n}$ so it is measurable. If $n$ is even take a non  measurable set $A$ and define $f(x)=1$ if $x \in A$, $-1$ otherwise. Then $f^{n}$ is measurable but $f$ is not.